# How to find/replace a specific ANSI escape code in all STDOUT/STDERR from any source

Tags: terminal, zsh, zshrc, ansi-escape, alacritty

My terminal background colour is dark blue.

A few tools that I use emit dark blue text regardless, making the text invisible to me.

Can I add something to my `.zshrc` that will read all STDOUT/STDERR from any/every source and automatically replace any dark blue ANSI escape code with a white one?

From my `alacritty.yml`:

```
colors:
  primary:
    background: '0x002b36'
    foreground: '0x839496'
    dim_background: '0x002b36'
    dim_foreground: '0x839496'
    bright_background: '0x002b36'
    bright_foreground: '0x839496'
  cursor:
    text:   '#002b36' # base03
    cursor: '#839496' # base0
  normal:
    black: '0x073642'
    red: '0xdc322f'
    green: '0x859900'
    yellow: '0xb58900'
    blue: '0x268bd2'
    magenta: '0xd33682'
    cyan: '0x2aa198'
    white: '0xeee8d5'
  bright:
    black: '0x002b36'
    red: '0xcb4b16'
    green: '0x586e75'
    yellow: '0x657b83'
    blue: '0x839496'
    magenta: '0x6c71c4'
    cyan: '0x93a1a1'
    white: '0xfdf6e3'
```

From my `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U colors
colors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no, not from your `.zshrc` file, but you can edit your `alacritty.yml` file. In there, under `normal:`, replace the value of `blue:` with another value of your choice. You can read more about setting these values in the [example `alacritty.yml` file](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/6f135d713a742a76b548f2efa179356f702e0743/alacritty.yml#L269) distributed with Alacritty.

Comment: I think that, if one really wants to, one **can** do it from within .zshrc : `exec ( zsh -i -f  2>&1 | filter)`, where `filter` is the program which removes the offending escape sequences. Needless to say that this approach has so many drawbacks that I would not seriously consider it as alternative.